# The resource cannot be found error on clicking a link

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have this html page. When I click on a link    `<a href="~/FloorPlan/UserLabFloor">`on html page it throws an error "The resource cannot be found" I am unable to get the issue.

Here is the html code (Index.cshtml)

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"></button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                <div class="panel panel-red">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <i class="fa fa-ticket fa-5x"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                <div class="huge"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin"></i></div>
                                <div>Budget</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <a href="~/FloorPlan/UserLabFloor">
                        <div class="panel-footer">
                            <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                            <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

UserLabFloor.cshtml:

```
@model  USTGlobal.WorkBench.UI.Models.FloorPlanViewModel 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RequestForm";

}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h2 class="page-header">Request Form</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            @using (Html.BeginForm("UserLabFloor", "FloorPlan"))
            {
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Period:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Quarter", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q1", Value = "1" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q2", Value = "2" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q3", Value = "3" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "Q4", Value = "4" }) }, "-- Select Quarter --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                    <br />
                                    @Html.DropDownList("Year", new SelectListItem[] { (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2016", Value = "2016" }), (new SelectListItem() { Text = "2017", Value = "2017" }) }, "-- Select Year --", new { @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Line ID:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.floorConfig.LineID, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Project:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.floorConfig.Project, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-horizontal">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="control-label col-lg-4">Budget:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.floorConfig.Budget, new { onkeypress = "return isNumberKey(event)", @class = "form-control" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-4" style="padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                        <input type="button" id="btnCancel" value="Clear" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" />
                    </div>
                </div>

            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

FloorPlanController.cs

```
[ActionName("UserLabFloor")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UserLabFloor()
        {
            FloorConfirguration floorConfig = new FloorConfirguration();

            floorService.SaveLabFloorConfig(floorConfig);

            return View("UserLabFloor");

        }
```

Comment: Use `href="@Url.Action("UserLabFloor", "FloorPlan")"` to generate the correct url.

Comment: This isn't working for me.

Comment: Then you do not have a public method named `UserLabFloor()` in `FloorPlanController`

Comment: I have updated the code with UserLabFloor.cshtml and FloorPlanController. Please have a lot. I have added public method but I am getting the same error.

Comment: All you have shown is a POST method (a link goes to a GET method)

Comment: oh! basically my userlabfloor code is a form..i need to enter the data and on submit button it needs to store that in the db. How should i go here with GET?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150163/discussion-between-beginner-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: You dont. Use use a form with a submit button and POST to your method (your changing data so it needs to be a POST)

Comment: You need to have one GET method which should be called when a user clicks on the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Nirman have mentioned you're missing a GET handler in your `FloorPlanController.cs`.

You're returning the `UserLabFloor` view after the form submission (POST) but you didn't have the `[HttpGet]` definition for your `UserLabFloor()` method.

This means that the browser will issue a GET request after the POST but there's no matching route (404) in the MVC RouteTable in this case.

To understand more about this behaviour, please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get